# Type-check in method of child class

Tags: java

In Java, I have parent `class P` and a child `class C.`

In an **abstract class**, I have a method `void blah(P parent)`. In a **child class of the abstract class**, it doesn't compile by having `void blah(C child)`.

How do I achieve the type check in the child class?

Comment: +1. I think this is partly possible with generics, though probably not in a really satisfactory fashion. It does somewhat go against the Liskov substitution principle after all. Waiting for a good answer by someone who has tried that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void blah(P parent)` and `void blah(C child)` are actually different methods.  That's why you can not use the C Child to override an abstract P parent method.

So, in your child class of the abstract class, you can either

```
void blah(P parent){
  if(parent instanceof C){
     ...
  }else if(parent instanceof C2){

  }
}
```

Or just implement these two methods separately.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use parent type parameter instead having the child parameter. If you use it you can pass any implementation or you abstract class and it will make you code reusable.

In your case you have two different methods and which is not an overridden method.